Printing Failing from HQ ERP print jobs to Site printers after Network/hardware update
Questioning a set up, short story:
I have a client set up where their HQ is site W and their locations are sites are X-Z.
Site W is where the on-prem solution exists, sites X-Z can access on-prem solution, however printing has become more daunting after a network and hardware upgrade.
Firewall and Network switches went from Sonicwall >> WatchGuard (Client has 3rd party network support).
Prior to the changes, the on-prem solution would work like this. ERP print function > send command to linux > linux has host configuration and CUPS configuration with printers mapped. Print job would execute and send to sites X-Z from site W.
Now we get "unable to print data broken pipe" - after setting up printers again, first print would work only after 5 minutes. This led me to review the routes designated by who ever originally set up the linux server.
Site W is 192.168.1.0
Site X is 192.168.30.0
Site Y is 192.168.40.0
Site Z is 192.168.50.0
Gateway to site W is 192.168.1.132
There is a route rule from destination 192.168.30.30 to gateway 192.168.1.132 set with UHG on a bridge that isn't making any sense, I'm not sure the relevancy of this information. As the remaining routes on the linux server for the other sites do not exist.
There were previous NAT rules on the server, but confirming that we turned off the native FW for RHEL 6.5 then removed the NAT rules as we may have been double NAT'ing from the FWs active policies to the servers.
Confirming I can telnet to the printers from ssh, however when I ping the printers, I get 8 good hops then a 40 second time out, then 8 more hops then another 40 second time out.
Any help here would be appreciated. Our thoughts here are really leaning toward the configuration on the new firewall and switches, but I want to rule out any and all speculative items since this seems more network related than server side since printing from ERP at site W works as intended, and printing to external networked printers works as intended.

That would be to destination 192.168.30.30 via gateway 192.168.1.132 (not 'from', hence 'destination')... although it is indeed an odd route (not least because I wouldn't expect the server to need any routes beyond a default route). Can you draw a diagram? it's unclear where the problematic printers are and where you're pinging them from – are they on the same subnet as the machine running ping, or are they in another site entirely?

Hey thanks for the response,The printers physically exist at sites X-Z on the site subnet.
The host file has the IPs/names of the printers on the linux server at Site W.
This previously worked prior to the network/hardware change, but something is preventing our printing from the ERP from working.
The way this works - ERP is on Site W, The front end user connects to a client (erp) that is supported by progress on a linux backend. There are commands on the front end that sent print jobs down through programs existing on the linux server.

We confirmed that users at Site W can print as intended. So we know the workflow for the printers are doing exactly what is intended. Its just anything going to the sites.

From a windows server at site W, you can ping the printers without any delay or skipped hops. From the linux server, the ping is sporadic and does 8 hops in succession, times out for 40 seconds, then hits 8 successful hops again.

From sites X-Z - you can ping the Linux server at Site W (from my understanding, network partner confirmed this).

So a linear diagram:
User X logs into ERP > Runs a print job from an old interface to printer A > printer A has a configuration to send a command to linux to route application data through software to compile and sent PCL code down to a printer > Linux handles this part then on data translation -- fails to complete because the connection times out between data sends.

What does the routing table look like on the Linux server? (From ip route, not from the old route/netstat.) And does the Linux server's ip route get <printer_ip> fibmatch select the same gateway as (Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress <printer_ip>)[1] on the Windows server?
